# No cast shadow in toon shader?

Tags: rendering, toon-shading

I was learning toon shadow in this Youtube video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J8RhUKituqs&lc=UgzoClbBcrLwmP-sll54AaABAg.9_tJGWes9eA9_v-gVT5vHi&ab_channel=MauroFanti
And the result was awesome. but I can't render the cast shadows between two objects.[image] For example, I put a cup on a table but the cast shadow of the cup can't render on the table. I also ask this question on his channel.

Comment: Are you in a rendered preview?  Do you have any lights in the scene?

Comment: Yes, of course. The point is each object has shadows on itself like different tones.

Comment: Okay, then we'd at least have to see the material, and preferably the file, to tell you what's happening.